# Deploy a Java App with a database, what users need to install?

Tags: java, mysql, database, derby

If I have a Java app (not web app, 100% local), that I want to deploy. Do user have to install something extra other than the `.jar` file if I use a database?

Also good point if anyone can say each case of this 3 different databases : 1. Java DB (Derby), 2. H2, 3. MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them, or if you want to install a database to the client, Java DB is an option included with Java SE distro. You also need a client drivers to make a connection to db. Derby also has an embedded database drivers, which you can embed to the application.

Comment: thanks Roman for answering the question. Two differen questions:          1.So the database pretty much automatically comes with the app itself ? . Behind the scene – will it create any table or something OR it will save the data in excel or any other similar things like that?                                           2. What do you mean with the client java db

Comment: it's difficult to understand what you mean a database, it's itself an app  and doesn't come with app. And yes it creates tables or something. If your app can save data to execel format it's not a database, unless office is installed and used as a database.

Comment: ... because it's a server app, a vendor provides drivers for clients to use in their client apps, a database is not a part of Java EE and it's language agnostic. However  Derby has a pure Java implementation  and could be used in the embedded option, this way it's running to the same process as Java client.

Comment: ... however H2 is also pure Java and could be embedded, and may be has less size of the class library, but you should compare features your application needs, ....

Comment: by -database- i mean a normal database, not "just a place to store data like excel." .  -Itself/comes with the app- i mean the same as before, we don't have to install other than the jar file itself.

Comment: good, do you want install a server standalone or embedded?

Comment: alright, its more clear now,Nice question  :D, hmm.. i think desktop app(not web app) means i don't need any server, right? so it willl embedded i guess... Sorry if u getting confuse, not speak java and english that well :D

Comment: java client is a program written in java that connects to the database server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78720/discussion-between-hilmanrdn-and-roman-c).